# Implementing a repo into Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to integrate a repo I found that uses composer with Laravel 5.1. 
This is the repo: https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats

So far I have added `"seostats/seostats": "dev-master"` to my `composer.json` and run `composer update`. It has pulled in the files.

Now I'm wondering how I can go about setting the Facades so they work.

The repo hasn't been set up specifically for L5.1 so i'm lost as how to actually use it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have a facade; it's not made for Laravel. Instead you'll just have to import the classes the normal way. For instance, here's the first example from the documentation you linked to:

```
use SEOstats\Services as SEOstats;

$url = 'http://www.google.com/';

// Create a new SEOstats instance.
$seostats = new \SEOstats\SEOstats;

// Bind the URL to the current SEOstats instance.
if ($seostats->setUrl($url)) {

    echo SEOstats\Alexa::getGlobalRank();
    echo SEOstats\Google::getPageRank();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting Seostats class not found with your solution, can you help me out ?

Comment: Sorry - I'd suggest posting a new question.

Comment: Not if it's unique and doesn't solve your problem. Sorry, but I can't give support for new issues in comments on two year old questions.

Comment: Ok I get what you mean, I've created a new unique question if you don't mind looking at it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523784/class-seostats-seostats-not-found-when-calling-seostats-instances-in-laravel-5