# Class 'SEOstats\SEOstats' not found when calling SEOStats instances in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.3, package

I am trying to use SEOstats php package in laravel, I've installed it using composer and then in my controller I have used it like below :

```
use SEOstats\Services as SEOstats;

class ReportageController extends Controller
{
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $url = 'http://www.google.com/';

        // Create a new SEOstats instance.
        $seostats = new \SEOstats\SEOstats;

        // Bind the URL to the current SEOstats instance.
        if ($seostats->setUrl($url)) {

            dd( SEOstats\Alexa::getGlobalRank());
        }
   }
}
```

The problem is I'm getting this error message :

`Class 'SEOstats\SEOstats' not found`

I've changed namespaces to different types but still getting this error. 
Any suggestion how to make it work in laravel 5.3

Comment: `use SEOstats\Services as SEOstats;` and `new \SEOstats\SEOstats;`. Choose one. Either don't have an alias for it, or use the alias.

Comment: I have successfully added the package to my laravel 5.5 project. Could you add your composer.json file for reference.

Answer (score 0):

`$seostats = new SEOstats;` will do the trick,

since you imported the class there is no need of the `\` prefix

Comment: I get :  Class 'SEOstats\Services' not found in response

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given alias as `SEOstats` then you have to use alias

```
use SEOstats\Services as SEOstats;

class ReportageController extends Controller
{
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $url = 'http://www.google.com/';

        // Create a new SEOstats instance.
        $seostats = new SEOstats;

        // Bind the URL to the current SEOstats instance.
        if ($seostats->setUrl($url)) {

            dd( SEOstats::getGlobalRank());
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I've used your solution and what is get is : 
Class 'SEOstats\Services' not found

Comment: let me istall once

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini.no even i am getting same issue let me dig more about this issue

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini.sorry not found.because its not actually laravel library so difficult .if i found i will post it